# Folder Synchronzation

Tags: wpf, mvvm, asynchronous, synchronization, mvvm-light

I have to implement kinda important feature. The feature for one-way synchronization of folders. There's a cloud server with folders of documents. And i need to synchronize some Windows folder with the structure and the documents of this remote folder.

The application is written in WPF, using MVVM (galasoft mvvm light toolkit). The job for syncing must be periodical (it must work every 5|10|100 etc minutes, depending on the user's properties). Of course it must be asynchronous.

I have three questions about it:

1. What are the best practices of implementing such a syncing job? Should i write it as a service of some structure or what?
2. How can i handle the periodicity of this job?
3. How can i vizualize in the system tray, that the job is on (can i use some circular progress bar on the icon of my app in the tray?)?

Thanks in advance, people!

Comment: Questions: is your sync process part of the desktop app, or does it have to run all the time ? What kind of local folder are you going to synchronize (local drive, network drive, what set of permissions do you need ?).

Comment: It's a part of the desktop app, when the app starts, it should do the syncing job, and then do it periodically. It works with the local drive (write permissions).

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Microsoft Sync Framework with its File Synchronization Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/bb887623).